# Is で marking end of the sentence in this case?

Tags: sentence

I was struggling with this sentence from Yoshimoto Banana story called ミイラ

> ...それは普通のセックス**で**普通に気持ちいいというものではなくて、何か歪んだ喜びだった。

My translation: it was kind of perverted pleasure, (何か歪んだ喜びだった)
              it was ordinary sex (それは普通のセックスで)
          (but) it wasn’t ordinarily pleasant (普通に気持ちいいというものではなくて)

How can I tell if というものではなくて negates only 普通に気持ちいい or if it also negates それは普通のセックスで? (so the translation would be "it wasn’t ordinary sex) Would there be a comma? Or am I getting this completely wrong?

I know this is kind of confused! Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You have parsed it wrong. That で in bold is not a copula (だ) but a simple case particle that marks a means/method/reason. 普通のセックスで here means "by/from (having) a normal sex".

> それは［｛普通のセックス**で**普通に気持ちいい｝というもの］ではなくて、…
>
> (Very literally: It was not an I-am-ordinarily-pleasant-**by**-having-an-ordinary-sex thing, but ...)
>
> → It was not an ordinary pleasure of an ordinary sex, but ...